Get no UUID from diskutil
On some (good) local volumes I can properly get the UUID.
On some (bad) local volumes I cannot get the UUID.
Why?
I use to get the disk UUID info with the Terminal command
diskutil info -plist /Volumes/macOS_10.2.6

and on some good volumes I properly get the UUID, among the other info, e.g.:
…
<string>IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/PEG2@1,2/UPSB@0/DSB2@2/XHC3@0</string>
<key>DiskUUID</key>
<string>6F8F4C3A-9334-4BEA-BA77-4B7AA13D116D</string>
<key>Ejectable</key>
<true/>
…

On some bad volumes I don't get the DiskUUID.
Also I use to get the UUID using the DiskArbitration methods, this way
DASessionRef    session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if(session)
{
    DADiskRef disk = DADiskCreateFromBSDName(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, diskID.UTF8String);
    if(disk)
    {
        CFDictionaryRef desk = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
        NSLog(@"desk is %@", desk);

        if(desk)
        {
            CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(desk, kDADiskDescriptionMediaUUIDKey);
            if(uuidRef){
                UUID = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef));
            }
            
            CFRelease(desk);
        }
        CFRelease(disk);
    }
    CFRelease(session);
}

On some good local volume I properly get the kDADiskDescriptionMediaUUIDKey value. On some other bad volumes The value UUID is missing. If I print the whole CFDictionaryRef desk variable I see
DAAppearanceTime = "756581625.559797";
DABusName = "usb-drd0-port-ss";
DABusPath = "IODeviceTree:/arm-io@10F00000/usb-drd0@82280000/usb-drd0-port-ss@00200000";
DADeviceInternal = 0;
DADeviceModel = ASM235CM;
DADevicePath = "IOService:/AppleARMPE/arm-io@10F00000/AppleH16GFamilyIO/usb-drd0@82280000/AppleT8132USBXHCI@00000000/usb-drd0-port-ss@00200000/USB3.0 Hub@00200000/AppleUSB30Hub@00200000/AppleUSB30HubPort@00210000/USB3.0 Hub@00210000/AppleUSB30Hub@00210000/AppleUSB30HubPort@00211000/USB3.1 Hub             @00211000/AppleUSB30Hub@00211000/AppleUSB30HubPort@00211300/USB3.1 Hub             @00211300/AppleUSB30Hub@00211300/AppleUSB30HubPort@00211330/ASM235CM@00211330/IOUSBHostInterface@0/IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub/IOUSBMassStorageDriverNub/IOUSBMassStorageUASDriver/IOSCSITargetDevice/IOSCSIHierarchicalLogicalUnit@0000000000000000/IOSCSIPeripheralDeviceType00/IOBlockStorageServices";
DADeviceProtocol = USB;
DADeviceRevision = 0;
DADeviceUnit = 34;

If I check on Disk Utility.app one of the bad local volumes, I get these info (see picture).

Anyway, as I have checked with other good local disks, the File system UUID value has nothing to do with the disk UUID I get using the 2 methods above.
Why can I get the UUID from some good local disk and not from some bad local disk? Are some disks not compatible with macOS?
